# My Site Cleanup and Secondary Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, onedrive-for-business

In the User Profile area of the Sharepoint admin center, you can elect to reroute permissions of an employee's OneDrive for Business site to another user when their profile is deleted. You also have the ability to specify a secondary Site Admin. No real issue here.

My question is what happens when both options are in play? If I have it set to allow access delegation to a specific user account when the manager is blank when the profile is deleted and have a secondary admin setup, what happens? Does it go to the delegated access account or does it bypass that since there is another listed admin?

Edit: I'm thinking that it will go to the replacement user based on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/06/25/top-recommendations-for-managing-the-my-site-cleanup-timer-job.aspx) by Kirk Evans, but it is for SP2010. Confirmation would be great though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to go out in the twittersphere and get an answer for this. In this scenario, I can assign a secondary administrator, this person will still have access, but the notifications and reassignment will occur on the user specified as the secondary owner.